# ListPlot using given columns of the data with many columns

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, column

Consider we have a table `table1` with $n$ columns. I want to [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) two given columns from the table.

For example

```
table1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 5}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume this is your data

```
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may want to plot column $5$ vs $3$.

```
ListPlot[data[[All, {3, 5}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you may want to plot them independently

```
ListPlot[
 Transpose@data[[All, {3, 5}]]
 , Joined -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or more general, choose any pair, *vs* or independently, using [`Manipuate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipuate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  If[vs, Identity, Transpose]@data[[All, {j, k}]]
  , Joined -> ! vs
  ]
 , {{j, 2}, Range[5], SetterBar}
 , {{k, 4}, Range[5], SetterBar}
 , {vs, {True, False}}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}[[All, 2 ;; 3]]
```