# Interactive plot labels

Tags: plotting, interactive, column

This question was inspired by [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179046/41058) answer.

Consider we have set of data:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 5}]
```

Command which allows to plot arbitrary the columns is

```
Manipulate[
 ListLogPlot[TableOutputTotal[[All, {j, k}]], 
  Joined -> True], {{j, 1}, Range[10], SetterBar}, {{k, 2}, Range[10],
   SetterBar}]
```

Is there any way to introduce interactive plot legends? Say, if I plot columns 1 and 2, there will be a legend "Quantity 1", "Quantity 2", for 3 and 5 there will be "Quantity 3", "Quantity 5" and so on.

Comment: What have you tried? if you understand the  other answer you could guess some and search for the rest. You must show your due diligence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have reproducible results you need to use [`SeedRandom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) prior to generating the random numbers.

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 5}];
```

There are only five columns so the controls should only go to five. To use [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) you must plot each column separately. This requires you to [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) the extracted data.

```
Manipulate[
 ListLogPlot[Transpose@data[[All, {j, k}]],
  Joined -> True,
  PlotLegends -> (Style[StringForm["Quantity ``", #], 14, Bold] & /@ {j, k})],
 Row[{
   Control[{{j, 1, Style["j", 14, Bold]}, Range[5], SetterBar}],
   Spacer[50],
   Control[{{k, 2, Style["k", 14, Bold]}, Range[5], SetterBar}]}]]
```

[image]